# webRTC 1:N(one to many) icecandidate event is now working

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc, nest

I am implementing a WebRTC 1:N scenario.
The host creates a room first, and other users join when the room is available. When the first user enters the room, both the host's video streaming and the video reception by the first user work correctly.
However, when the second user enters, the video transmission from the first user stops, and the second user does not receive the host's video. After logging, I realized that the icecandidate event, responsible for sending ICE information from the host to the second user, is not working.
How can I resolve this issue? I will attach the code below.

Please note that I am using a translation tool, and my explanations may not be entirely accurate.

#### front code

```
      //- offer -//
      socket.on('welcome', async (id) => {
        if (socket.id === roomManager) {
          console.log('welcome!', id);
          roomUsers.push(id);
          console.log('roomUsers', roomUsers);
          const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
          peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
          console.log('send offer roomManager -> ', offer, peerConnection);
          socket.emit('offer', { offer, title, id });
        }
      });

      //- offer -> answer -//
      socket.on('offer', async (offer) => {
        console.log('offer receive', socket.id, offer);
        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
          new RTCSessionDescription(offer),
        );
        const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(
          new RTCSessionDescription(answer),
        );
        console.log('send answer', answer, peerConnection);
        socket.emit('answer', { answer, title });
      });

      //- answer -//
      socket.on('answer', async (answer) => {
        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
          new RTCSessionDescription(answer),
        );
        console.log('receive answer', answer, peerConnection, roomUsers);
      });

      //- peer -//
      const makeConnection = () => {
        console.log('peer connect');
        peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
          iceServers: [
            {
              urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
            },
            {
              urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
            },
          ],
          iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
        });

        console.log('peerConnection', peerConnection);
        peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', handleIce);
        peerConnection.addEventListener('track', handleTrack);
        peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidateerror', (event) => {
          console.log(event);
        });

        if (roomManager === socket.id || roomManager === null) {
          stream
            .getTracks()
            .forEach((track) => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));
        }
      };

      //- ice event -//
      const handleIce = (ice) => {
        console.log('ice event');
        if (roomManager === socket.id) {
          const user = roomUsers[roomUsers.length - 1];
          console.log('ice -> user', user, ice);
          socket.emit('ice', { candidate: ice.candidate, title, user });
        } else {
          console.log('ice -> roomManager', ice);
          const user = null;
          socket.emit('ice', { candidate: ice.candidate, title, user });
        }
      };

      socket.on('ice', (ice) => {
        if (ice) {
          console.log('receive ice', ice);
          peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(ice));
        } else {
          console.log('No ice');
        }
      });

      //- stream -//
      const handleTrack = (data) => {
        console.log('handleTrack', data);
        if (socket.id !== roomManager) {
          liveVideo.srcObject = data.streams[0];
        }
      };
```

#### backend code

```
  //- offer -//
  @SubscribeMessage('offer')
  offer(@MessageBody() data, @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
    this.server.of('/').to(data.id).emit('offer', data.offer);
  }

  //- answer -//
  @SubscribeMessage('answer')
  answer(@MessageBody() data, @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
    this.server.of('/').to(this.roomManager).emit('answer', data.answer);
  }

  //- candidate -//
  @SubscribeMessage('ice')
  ice(@MessageBody() data, @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
    console.log('ice', data);
    if (data.user !== null) {
      this.server.of('/').to(data.user).emit('ice', data.candidate);
    } else {
      this.server.of('/').to(this.roomManager).emit('ice', data.candidate);
    }
  }
```

[I cannot upload images, so I have placed the console at the link below.](https://velog.io/@jw01987/console)

---

#### full code is here

[front](https://github.com/jeeeunu/1street/blob/live/views/live.ejs)

[back](https://github.com/jeeeunu/1street/blob/live/src/chat/chat.gateway.ts)

---

##### front

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="short icon" href="/img/logo.png" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 data-title="<%=title%>" id="title"><%=title%> live!</h1>
    <div>
      <video
        class="liveVideo"
        playsinline
        width="1000"
        height="800"
        autoplay
      ></video>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sound">mute</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary camera">camera off</button>
      <select
        id="cameraList"
        class="form-select"
        aria-label="Default select example"
      >
        <option value="device" selected disabled hidden>camera option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="chatList"></ul>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="chatInput"
          placeholder="chat"
        />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary chatInputBtn">채팅</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.3.2/socket.io.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KAZ4DtjNhLChOB/hxXuKqhMLYvx3b5MlT55xPEiNmREKRzeEm+RVPlTnAn0ajQNs"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      const socket = io('');
      const chatList = document.querySelector('.chatList');
      const title = document.querySelector('#title').getAttribute('data-title');
      const chatInput = document.querySelector('#chatInput');
      const chatInputBtn = document.querySelector('.chatInputBtn');
      const liveVideo = document.querySelector('.liveVideo ');
      const soundBtn = document.querySelector('.sound');
      const cameraBtn = document.querySelector('.camera');
      const cameraList = document.querySelector('#cameraList');

      /** @type {RTCPeerConnection} */
      let peerConnection;
      let roomManager = null;
      let stream;
      let isMuted = false;
      let isCameraOff = false;
      let roomUsers = [];
      window.onload = async () => {
        await joinRoom();
      };

      const joinRoom = async () => {
        await getMedia();

        makeConnection();
        socket.emit('join_room', title);
      };

      socket.on('room_manager', (id) => {
        roomManager = id;
      });

      //- chat -//
      chatInputBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        if (chatInput.value.replace(/ /g, '').length === 0) return;
        await socket.emit('chatInput', {
          chat: chatInput.value,
          roomName: title,
        });
        chatInput.value = '';
      });

      //- show chat -//
      socket.on('newMsg', (msg) => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = `${msg}`;
        chatList.append(li);
      });

      //- video -//
      const getMedia = async (deviceId) => {
        const defaultOption = {
          audio: true,
          video: { facingMode: 'user' },
        };
        const cameraOption = {
          audio: true,
          video: { deviceId: { exact: deviceId } },
        };
        try {
          stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
            deviceId ? cameraOption : defaultOption,
          );
          if (roomManager === null || socket.id === roomManager) {
            liveVideo.srcObject = stream;
          }
          if (!deviceId) {
            getCamera();
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };

      //- mute -//
      soundBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        stream.getAudioTracks().forEach((track) => {
          track.enabled = !track.enabled;
        });
        if (!isMuted) {
          soundBtn.innerText = 'unmute';
          isMuted = true;
        } else {
          soundBtn.innerText = 'mute';
          isMuted = false;
        }
      });

      //- camera on/off -//
      cameraBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        stream.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) => {
          track.enabled = !track.enabled;
        });
        if (!isCameraOff) {
          cameraBtn.innerText = 'on';
          isCameraOff = true;
        } else {
          cameraBtn.innerText = 'off';
          isCameraOff = false;
        }
      });

      //- camera info -//
      const getCamera = async () => {
        try {
          const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
          const cameras = devices.filter(
            (device) => device.kind === 'videoinput',
          );
          cameras.forEach((camera) => {
            const option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = camera.deviceId;
            option.innerText = camera.label;
            cameraList.appendChild(option);
          });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };

      //- camera change -//
      cameraList.addEventListener('input', async () => {
        await getMedia(cameraList.value);
        if (peerConnection) {
          const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
          const videoSender = peerConnection
            .getSenders()
            .find((sender) => sender.track.kind === 'video');
          videoSender.replaceTrack(videoTrack);
        }
      });

      //-  offer -//
      socket.on('welcome', async (id) => {
        if (socket.id === roomManager) {
          console.log('welcome!', id);
          roomUsers.push(id);
          console.log('roomUsers', roomUsers);
          const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
          peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
          console.log('send offer roomManager -> ', offer, peerConnection);
          socket.emit('offer', { offer, title, id });
        }
      });

      //- offer -> answer -//
      socket.on('offer', async (offer) => {
        console.log('offer receive', socket.id, offer);
        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
          new RTCSessionDescription(offer),
        );
        const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(
          new RTCSessionDescription(answer),
        );
        console.log('send answer', answer, peerConnection);
        socket.emit('answer', { answer, title });
      });

      //- answer -//
      socket.on('answer', async (answer) => {
        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
          new RTCSessionDescription(answer),
        );
        console.log('receive answer', answer, peerConnection, roomUsers);
      });

      //- peer -//
      const makeConnection = () => {
        console.log('peer connect');
        peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
          iceServers: [
            {
              urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
            },
            {
              urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
            },
          ],
          iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
        });


        console.log('peerConnection', peerConnection);
        peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', handleIce);
        peerConnection.addEventListener('track', handleTrack);
        peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidateerror', (event) => {
          console.log(event);
        });

        if (roomManager === socket.id || roomManager === null) {
          stream
            .getTracks()
            .forEach((track) => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));
        }
      };

      //- ice event -//
      const handleIce = (ice) => {
        console.log('ice event');
        if (roomManager === socket.id) {
          const user = roomUsers[roomUsers.length - 1];
          console.log('ice -> user', user, ice);
          socket.emit('ice', { candidate: ice.candidate, title, user });
        } else {
          console.log('ice -> roomManager', ice);
          const user = null;
          socket.emit('ice', { candidate: ice.candidate, title, user });
        }
      };

      socket.on('ice', (ice) => {
        if (ice) {
          console.log('receive ice', ice);
          peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(ice));
        } else {
          console.log('No ice');
        }
      });

      //- stream -//
      const handleTrack = (data) => {
        console.log('handleTrack', data);
        if (socket.id !== roomManager) {
          liveVideo.srcObject = data.streams[0];
        }
      };

      socket.on('disconnectRoom', (id) => {
        roomUsers = roomUsers.filter((user) => {
          return user !== id;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

##### back(server)

```
import {
  ConnectedSocket,
  MessageBody,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  OnGatewayInit,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
})
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  roomManager: string;

  constructor() {}

  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;

  handleConnection(@ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
    this.server.emit('roomChange', this.publicRooms());
  }

  handleDisconnect(socket: Socket) {
    this.server.emit('disconnectRoom', socket.id);
    this.server.emit('roomChange', this.publicRooms());
  }

  //- chat -//
  @SubscribeMessage('chatInput')
  chat(@MessageBody() data, @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
    this.server.of('/').to(data.roomName).emit('newMsg', data.chat);
  }

  //- room join -//
  @SubscribeMessage('join_room')
  joinRoom(@MessageBody() data, @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
    console.log('id', socket.id);
    if (!this.publicRooms().hasOwnProperty(data)) {
      socket.join(data);
      this.roomManager = socket.id;
      console.log('roomManager', this.roomManager, data);
      this.server.of('/').to(data).emit('room_manager', socket.id);
    } else {
      console.log('user', socket.id, data);
      socket.join(data);
    }
    this.server.emit('roomChange', this.publicRooms());
    socket.to(data).emit('welcome', socket.id);
  }

  //- all rooms -//
  publicRooms() {
    const {
      adapter: { sids, rooms },
    } = this.server.of('/');
    const publicRoom = {};
    rooms.forEach((_, key) => {
      if (sids.get(key) === undefined) {
        publicRoom[key] = this.countRoom(key);
      }
    });
    return publicRoom;
  }

  //- count -//
  countRoom(roomName) {
    return this.server.of('/').adapter.rooms.get(roomName)?.size;
  }

  //- webRTC -//

  //- offer -//
  @SubscribeMessage('offer')
  offer(@MessageBody() data, @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
    this.server.of('/').to(data.id).emit('offer', data.offer);
  }

  //- answer -//
  @SubscribeMessage('answer')
  answer(@MessageBody() data, @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
    this.server.of('/').to(this.roomManager).emit('answer', data.answer);
  }

  //- candidate -//
  @SubscribeMessage('ice')
  ice(@MessageBody() data, @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
    console.log('ice', data);
    if (data.user !== null) {
      this.server.of('/').to(data.user).emit('ice', data.candidate);
    } else {
      this.server.of('/').to(this.roomManager).emit('ice', data.candidate);
    }
  }
}
```